# Include paths in C++ CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I have included `<time.h>` in my C++ program I create in Eclipse `C++` `Cmake` project that runs on Ubuntu.  I'm trying to navigate to `<time.h>` file, but get error `could not find include file 'time.h' in include paths`.

Where I can set include paths in my `C++ CMake` project?

Comment: Try with <ctime>.

Comment: <ctime> works fine. What is wrong with <time.h> >

Comment: Please copy-paste your minimal `main.cpp` that demonstrates the problem. I smell a typo of some sort.

Comment: I don't know how Eclipse handle include paths whether does it ship with a compiler or uses an existing one on the system. So hard to guess. Probably something related with finding C standard headers.

Answer (score 0):

`time.h` is a system header so even if Eclipse is not able to navigate to it the compiler should still be able to find it.

Selecting `Index -> Search For Unresolved Includes` in the context menu of the project will give you the list of unresolved includes which you can search in `/usr/include` and add containing directories to `C++ Include Paths and Symbols` in Project Properties.

On my system I had to add `/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu` for `bits/c++config.h` to be resolved and a few more directories.

Don't forget to rebuild the index (Index -> Rebuild) after adding include directories.

Answer (score -1):

First, to tell CMake to add the directory as -I to the compilation command line, you use include directories(). Second, in your add executable() or add library() call, you list the headers. When contrasted with other ways of making Makefile, CMake is more like a script language.